# Is it possible in C++ to loop over all subclasses of an Abstract class?

Tags: c++, macros, template-meta-programming

I have an abstract class in C++ with several subclasses.

Is it somehow by Macros or template metaprogramming possible to do something like that:

```
foreach subclass of Base:
  mymap[subclass::SOME_CONSTANT] = new subclass();
```

Comment: No. The compiler cannot possibly know whether you in some other translation unit adds yet one more subclass. Or link to a library that adds a subclass.

Comment: No. Maybe if you tell us why you want to do this, we can provide a solution.

Comment: While, AFAIK, this may not be done without manual registration (which is the preferred and safe approach), but you can use [Typelists](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-programmingtypelists-and-applica/184403813) to alleviate the tedious registration code.

Comment: Also check these: **To Code or Not to Code**, [Part 1](http://web.archive.org/web/20050423211353/http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-jun00.pdf) and [Part 2](http://web.archive.org/web/20050423211353/http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/ph-mar00.pdf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot.

What you want, apparently, is a `Factory` (or perhaps `Abstract Factory`).

In C++, you setup a Factory class and register builders.

```
class FooFactory
{
public:
  typedef std::function<Foo*()> Builder;

  /// returns true if the registration succeeded, false otherwise
  bool Register(std::string const& key, Builder const& builder) {
    return map.insert(std::make_pair(key, builder)).second;
  }

  /// returns a pointer to a new instance of Foo (or a derived class)
  /// if the key was found, 0 otherwise
  Foo* Build(std::string const& key) const {
    auto it = _map.find(key);
    if (it == _map.end()) { return 0; } // no such key
    return (it->second)();
  }

private:
  std::map<std::string, Builder> _map;
};
```

You can create a singleton of this factory, to register the derived classes during library load, which is handy for plugins-like architecture:

```
FooFactory& GetFooFactory() { static FooFactory F; return F; }
```

And you can prepare a handy builder:

```
template <typename Derived>
Foo* fooBuilder() { return new Derived(); }
```

Then people are expected to register their derived classes in the factory:

```
static const bool registeredBar =
    GetFooFactory().Register("Bar", fooBuilder<Bar>);
```

Note: it is far from being mandatory that the factory should be a singleton, though it's not as evil here because it's constant once the load of the libraries ends.

Note: for a proper plugin architecture, you'd need to use RAII (instead of a bool), to handle the unregistration at library unload. It's much rarer though.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not allow to iterate over types. Also enumeration of enum members are not possible. See this:

```
enum Color
{
    red,
    green,
    blue=5,
    yellow
};
```

Further the C++ compiler compiles compilation units independent. You can imaging that it cannot known when compiling the base class implementation that the class will be inherited sometimes.